# Scrapy crawls on <button rel="next">

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawls data on kogan.com
The 'next page' is a button with `rel="next"` attribute without `href`. Moreover, I try to manually add page number to the `url`, but the `page` number is limited to `page=10` only and cannot go further (`>10`). For example, I type `page=11`, the `url` remains in `page=10`. So I assume it is the anti-scrapy mechanism of this site? The only way to have page number beyond 10 is to click the `<button>`.
Below is the link I am crawling on.
https://www.kogan.com/au/shop/phones/?page=10

```
<button class="_11Gvc wJWlF" rel="next"><span>View more</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This website has pretty nice API, so you can use this instead. Check links in developer tools:

```
https://www.kogan.com/api/v1/products/?department=phones&group_variants=true&store=au&offset=360
```

So, you can iterate in cycle through all the pages, changing `offset` and get all available items.

Comment: Where did you find this API? just type `.com/api` to find if the site has API?

Comment: For example in chrome: Developer tools -> Network tab. Scroll page and you will see this request in list.

Comment: ohh, thx a lot. But back to my question, is there any alternative way to get `page` number beyond 10?

Comment: I go through this JSON file and in the `objects`, a list to hold items, is still `36` which is the number for 1 page regardless of the value of  `offset`.

Comment: But did you see that for different offsets these objects are different? So offset=0, 36, 72, 108, etc and you will get every time different object, so you can scrape whole batch.